# Working outside of request context runtime error

Tags: python, sql, database, flask, sqlalchemy

i am trying to do flask run on command line, but i am getting this error from it. it doesnt tell me what line or anything.

also I am very much a beginner but learning.

*

```
*
```

import os
        import requests
        from flask import current_app as app
        from tables import *
        from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, url_for, session, request

```
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
    session["user_id"]
    app = Flask(__name__)

    res = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json", params={"key": "...", "isbns": "9781632168146"})
    db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"]=os.getenv("postgres:...")
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"]=False
    db.init_app(app)


    #creating tables
    class books(db.tables):
        __tablename__="books"
        title=db.column(db.string, nullable=False)
        author=db.column(db.string, nullable=False)
        ISBN=db.column(db.string, nullable=False)
        year=db.column(db.string, nullable=False)

    class reviews(db.tables):
        __tablename__="reviews"
        id=db.column(db.integer, primary_key=True)
        r=db.column(db.string, nullable=False)

    class users(db.tables):
        __tablename__="users"
        username=db.column(db.string, nullable=False)
        password=db.column(db.password, nullable=False)

    def main():
        db.create_all()

    @app.route('/register', methods=["POST"])
    def register():
        #insert
            return render_template("register.html")


    @app.route('/login', methods=["POST"])
    def login():
            username = request.form('username')
            password = request.form('password')
            id = request.form("")
            db.execute(SELECT)
            return render_template("login.html" "username"==username, "password"==password)

    @app.route('/search', methods=["POST"])
    def search():
            ISBN = request.form('ISBN')
            title = request.form('title')
            author = request.form('author')
            year = request.form('year')
            reviewcount = request.form('author')
            db.execute(SELECT)
            return render_template("search.html" "ISBN"==ISBN, "title"==title, "author"==author, "year"==year, "reviewcount"==reviewcount )

    @app.route('/results')
    def result():
            db.execute()
            return render_template("results.html" "ISBN"==ISBN, "title"==title, "author"==author,)
    """
    @app.route("/logout")
            return render_template("logout.html")

    @app.route("/api/<isbn>")
            return render_template("book.html")
    """

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
```

*

*

Comment: Try to take a deeper look, there should be any type of error and its description then update your answer

Comment: Please fix your formatting.